# Scrolling from the middle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have added a scrollview to my layout, however, when the activity loads, the scrollview is not viewed from the top but rather somewhere in middle, and where a user has to scroll up in order the see the above fields. I would prefer if the scrollview was set to top.

With support, I tried to achieve this programmingly, however, my attempts have been unsuccessful. In particular, I was advise to use the following code, but that hasn't been effective.

```
ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile);
         s.scrollTo(0,s.getTop());
```

Below is the activity code

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);
        ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile);
         s.scrollTo(0,s.getTop());



        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();


                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 
                    currentUser.put("name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });




        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Below is the layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_blue" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="797dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtname"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#330099"
        android:text="Upload from Facebook"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:text="Select photo from gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Preferred Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="Please type your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:text="Female" />

    </RadioGroup>

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Search Distance (100KM)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMaxAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tMaxAge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="50"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="I agree to the terms and Conditions"
            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView16"
             android:layout_width="280dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Click here to review the terms and conditions"
             android:textColor="#99CCFF"
             android:textSize="16sp" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnReset"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
             android:alpha="0.8"
             android:background="#660000"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:text="Reset"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="17sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
             android:alpha="0.8"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
             android:background="#330099"
             android:text="Confirm"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="17sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
             android:layout_width="270dp"
             android:layout_height="70dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:ems="10"
             android:hint="A quick description of yourself"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
             android:textSize="18dp" >

             <requestFocus />
         </EditText>

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/etxtage"
             android:layout_width="230dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
             android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
             android:ems="10"
             android:hint="Please type your age here"
             android:inputType="number"
             android:maxLength="2"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
             android:textSize="18dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/bRemove"
             android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:text="Age"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it like this, first add

```
android:id="@+id/main" to RelativeLayout:
```

so it will be :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="797dp"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and in onCreate

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

v.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately none of these three options seems to work.

Comment: if any of help, when it launches it is focus on the edittext under "headline" etxtheadline

Comment: add these to your top root view android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: or: ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile).requestFocus();

Comment: Thanks man for the solution. I will use this solution for now. This has indirectly resolve the issue. In the sense that it mask the issue of forcing the scrollview to start on top regardless of the conditions that were applied. With this it is starting from top only because it is focused on an edittext that is situated on top.

Comment: i think this android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" or ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile).requestFocus(); should work weather you have edit text or not

Comment: i suggest you change the question title to "ScrollView starts from the middle"

Comment: Oh I badly applied the suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Al thought with your third option, I receive the following error: Cannot cast from boolean to ScrollView

Comment: let me check in eclipse

Comment: solved it and test it on your project, answer has been updated. please tell me if it works or not